# Using Direct Connect access to ArcGIS databases in standalone applications

Tags: oracle, delphi, stack-overflow, arcgis, arcgis-server

I work in an enterprise designing, creating and maintening custom applications on the base of ESRI ArcGIS. Some customers use Direct Connect, to connect to databases stored on Oracle or MS SQLServer. I have a problem with a standalone application for several months now.

I have an application, written in Delphi. One of the first things I do, of course, is opening the workspace.

```
pWorkspaceFactory:= CoSdeWorkspaceFactory.Create as IWorkspaceFactory;
pWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile('D:\directconnect.sde', WndHandle, pWorkspace);
```

This works fine for all "normal" connects, in some cases of direct connect it works fine too. But it may happen that I get on a different database a stackoverflow when calling OpenFromFile. Raising the MaxStackSize in the project options of the delphi project made it work on some Direct Connect databases. But it doesn't work for all.

Does anybody know the correct way to handle Direct Connects in standalone applications, without ArcMap? Accessing the databases in ArcMap has never been a problem, I think ArcMap has a special handling for Direct Connects.

Thanks for all ideas and replies. May the answer be with you ;-)

Greetings

warheart

Comment: I can't answer the question, but I do have a suggestion about the question.  Could you add more information about the stack overflow, please?  What code is it in - does OpenFromFile call back into your code, or is it solely in theirs?  If you look at the call stack, what is happening?  (Eg, recursive, or simply a gigantic call tree?)  Simply saying it overflows may not really  help, unless you're looking for an answer that doesn't involve using their code at all.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comment. I can't post more details about the exception at the moment, because I can't reproduce it on my testdatabases. It's only out in the wild the exception occurs. But I can say that it happens in a (for me) closed ESRI-Dll, i cannot see the call stack of the dlls methods (OpenFromFile is an ESRI-Method in an ESRI-Dll). I would like to post such things, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with the DC library you are using? There are separate libraries for each version of ArcGIS and each flavor of database.